# How to Remove Script in Script from Jenkinsfile Steps

Tags: jenkins

I am not sure how I would untangle this step in a declarative Jenkinsfile. I was told you cannot have a script inside of a script, so I am looking for help on how this could be refactored.

```
stage('Publish Procurement') {
  steps {
      script: '''
        if (0 != sh(script: "git diff --exit-code modules/procurement", returnStatus: true)) {
          node_modules/.bin/ng build test-library
          cd modules/test-library/dist/
          node_modules/.bin/ng test test-library
        }
      '''
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help that is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
stage('Publish Procurement') {
  steps {
      returnCode = sh(script: "git diff --exit-code modules/procurement", returnStatus: true)
      if ( 0 != returnCode){
          script: '''
                    node_modules/.bin/ng build test-library
                    cd modules/test-library/dist/
                    node_modules/.bin/ng test test-library
                '''
      }
  }
}
```

You can always store the output of sh to a variable and then use that variable for performing any kind of valid operations.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this